# MySQL: How to update remote webserver with differential data

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, database-replication

On my local machine, I maintain several InnoDB tables which are mirror replica of the ones on my web server. Whenever I have new or updated data, I perform that on the local tables. For the updates, it's typically to only a few fields of some tables. Doing locally helps me to perform processing and validation of the data before staging. Finally, I want to move these differential data to the remote server.

How can I best achieve this whole process of data migration. There are a few stages where I am looking for your inputs/experience:

- Commands to identify and fetch the differential data from all the tables,
- On the remote site, commands to update the respective tables with this data,
- How can I ensure atomicity of the updates to not break the integrity of the
  webpage contents created with it.

I am planning to automate this whole process. In future, there can be 1000s of such updates and hence I would like to have this time and size optimized.

I use python and plan to use fabric to run the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to use the binary log to record changes to the local database.  Then you just need to convert the binary log to an SQL script with the [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) tool, and apply that to your web site.  Sort of the same process as performing point-in-time recovery.

Use [FLUSH LOGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html) (or [mysqladmin flush-logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html)) on the local system when you're done converting the local binlogs to SQL.  That way you know exactly where you left off, and you can start there next time you upload changes.

I'm not sure about applying the changes on the web server in a truly atomic way.  You'd have to use a transaction to do that.  You could sandwich the SQL script in between START TRANSACTION and COMMIT, but I'd want to make sure the binlog itself doesn't contain transaction statements.

Another tool to compare two databases and figure out the minimal set of changes is Percona Toolkit's [pt-table-sync](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-table-sync.html).  But that tool is usually meant to make the databases identical.  You likely have production data on your web server that isn't in the local developer instance, so you may need to filter to specific tables or maybe pt-table-sync has an "insert but don't delete" option or something.  I encourage you to read the doc carefully and experiment on test instances.

Comment: In the local tables, for rows there will be instances of updates, undo or changes following a review, etc. Will not the log file become noisy?

Comment: What do you think about Xtrabackup's recipie of 'Making an incremental backup', www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/howtos/recipes_xbk_inc.html. What I am thinking is during the time of update, I first get the full backup of the respective tables on production server, then using that as reference to make an incremental backup on the local machine and finally using it to update the production server. Is this any option? Are there any holes?  (NOTE: I also need to try out pt-table-sync).

Comment: You can't mix & match incremental physical backups from different MySQL instances.  The binlog solution I gave would do kind of the same   thing, but as logical backups that are independent of physical instance.

Comment: Apart from FLUSH LOGS, is there any other method to start off from where I synced last time? Reading FLUSH LOG, I tend to feel that it may not be a sure-shot way to take off from previous as there may be say, human error with issuing FLUSH LOGS multiple times, etc.

Comment: Any way you do it, you need some way of remembering what binlog file & position was current when you last did a sync.  Using FLUSH LOGS makes it a little bit easier because then you're dealing with whole binlog files instead of having to remember offsets within the binlog file.

Comment: Thanks, got you. Regarding bin logs, can I configure mysql for bin logs for only a select few tables?

Comment: Not for specified tables, but you can filter bin logs based on the database.  There are some nuances, so read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db

Comment: I have a query related to mysqlbinlog: I don't find an option to change the target database name. That's not really a problem, but a flexibility. Do you know if it can be done?

Comment: No, I don't think you can change operations in the binlog to apply to a different database name as you reply them.  I mean you could hack it by editing the output of mysqlbinlog, but that would be hard to get right.

Comment: The output of mysqlbinlog is in base64 and not able to get it in string. Can I get it in ascii to modify?

Comment: Not sure, try reading the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html

Comment: I am using the binlog method to sync my webserver databases with local database changes. Now, once I perform the changes, I need to know which rows are modified/inserted/deleted. Is there's an easy way to do this using the binlog data or on the webserver?

Comment: Not an easy way, no... my best suggestion would be to keep a copy of the original database and use `pt-table-sync` to diff them.  You can use the `--print` option to report the differences instead of acting on them.